# How do I code a spline model with degree of 1 with different knots?

Tags: r, spline

I'm trying to code a multivariate spline model with some independent variables having multiple knots and some having none.  The variables with splines will always have a degree of one.  I have some code but I don't know if I trust it because I haven't done a spline regression in r (only in some proprietary "black box" software).  Below is the code.

I have checked a lot of the 6,000 posts on splines.  I see so many different codes that I'm confused.

Will anyone either 
a)tell me if this code is doing what I want it to do (degree = 1/different knots)
b)is there a better way to do this?

```
fit1 <- glm(freq ~ channel + term2 + pay_plan_bucket_2 + 
          state + eff_year + marital_status + 
          vehicle_type + insured_age_bucket + I(pmax(0, insured_age_bucket- 
26)) + I(pmax(0, insured_age_bucket - 70)) +
          vehicle_length_bucket + I(pmax(0, vehicle_length_bucket - 45)) + 
          veh_age + I(pmax(veh_age -7)) + I(pmax(veh_age - 18)) +
          rba_bucket + I(pmax(0, rba_bucket - 3500)) + I(pmax(0, rba_bucket - 27000)) +
          credit_tier_bucket + I(pmax(0, credit_tier_bucket - 3)),
        family=quasipoisson(link="log"), 
        data=comp_training_set_newpayplan)
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is most likely off-topic for SO (no minimally reproducible example) as well as the stats companion, CV. Nonetheless, a cursory inspection suggests to me that the code is correct. [See my relevant CV post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225653/periodic-splines-to-fit-periodic-data/319760#319760).

Comment: I don't think those can be accurately called splines (or even knots). They are not even continuous when you have more than one "knot", much less differentiable at any of the knots.

Comment: Thanks @42.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: @Jordan you are forgetting to add `0` to the list of arguments to `pmax`. Possibly explaining why you may be getting nonsensical results.

Comment: If I understand what is desired (piecewise linear regression at predetermined junctions), then think this has all been done in the `segmented` package (and probably others as well.)

Comment: And if the segmented pkg is not what is needed then you need to figure out what the second and higher spline values are and use that value rather than 0 in your pmax call. So instead of the second `I(.)`-expression, I _think_ it would be `+ I(pmax(26, insured_age_bucket - 70))`

Answer (score 1):

Your brute force approach to splines is probably correct. Verify your output using `bs` from the splines package, for instance: `bs(credit_tier_bucket, knots=3, degree=1)` as a single term in the formula. Since the basis is formed differently than you have done here, gather the predicted values from both models and verify they are equal to ensure the two approaches to coding splines provides equivalent estimation and inference.

Comment: Thanks @AdamO.  Upon doing what you said, the fitted values are close but not close enough to be comfortable.  The basic plot of the residuals are close in pattern, even though the pattern does not look great.  Thanks as always for the reply.

Comment: @Jordan you may want to edit your post for a simpler and reproducible example. The `motor` dataset from the `boot`/`MASS` package is a good one.